# How can I authenticate frontend app to access IAP protected backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

My goal is to make some apps (frontend + backend) private only in GCP. To do this I plan to use Identity Aware Proxy and allow only people from `@example.com` domain. I've checked [documentation and tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/how-to) but I still cannot figure out if is its possible to authenticate standard frontend app with backend API protected by GCP IAP.

My ideal scenario would be like this:

- `example.com` - frontend js app, running in browser, protected by IAP, doing requests to backend
- `api.example.com` - backend API also protected by IAP (different GCP project)

When going into `example.com` I get a redirect to Google auth. After providing valid credentials I'm redirected back to `example.com` and now I can see and use frontend app. This app will then make requests to `api.example.com` that should also be authenticated.

Is this even possible? Would I not get 401 error or auth redirect response from backend service?

Another scenario that could work for me:

- `example.com` - frontend js app, running in browser, publicly available, making requests to bckend
- `api.example.com` - backend API protected by IAP (different GCP project)

Can I somehow detect that backend is IAP protected and redirect to auth page **but go back to `example.com`** after google authentication?

When doing `curl` to IAP protected backend I only get `302` response with google auth url

```
$ curl -i https://example.com
HTTP/2 302
set-cookie: GCP_IAP_XSRF_NONCE_XXXX=1; expires=Thu, 15-Feb-2024 12:22:44 GMT; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=....
x-goog-iap-generated-response: true
date: Thu, 15 Feb 2024 12:12:44 GMT
content-type: text/html
server: Google Frontend
content-length: 36
via: 1.1 google
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000

Invalid IAP credentials: empty token
```

In theory I could check `x-goog-iap-generated-response` header but how do I force IAP and google to redirect me to frontend app domain instaed of `api.example.com` after authentication with google?

Thank you

// EDIT

To clarify my problem is not how to send auth token to backend. My problem is how to obtain this token when there is frontend & backen app and at least backend is IAP protected. When doing request to backend without auth token I get 302 and redirect url to authorization page on google. After I submit proper credentials I'm redirected to original page and then I can use this page (because auth cookies are set I think). But problem is tat I want to be redirected to frontend app domain after backend authentication and then I want to be able to do authorized requests to backend from now on.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your curl command must include the HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer OIDC-IDENTITY-TOKEN`. I am not sure what you mean by ***allow only people from @example.com domain***. The token is used for authorization and not the source domain.

Comment: @JohnHanley I know that I should send `Authorization` token but question is how my frontend app can get this token and then send it with request to backend API? About domain access with IAP you can restrict who has access to IAP protected resource using IAM permissions. There you can define users, service accounts, groups and even whole domain like `member = "domain:example.com"`. Anyway, this i not my problem.

Comment: Study this section: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 This part is for web based apps: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow